# Consuming a 3rd Party WSDL

Tags: wsdl, wsdl2apex

I'm hoping you can help. I have a 3rd party WSDL that i'm trying to load into Salesforce, but I seem to be hitting some issues. I've loaded it in, and whenever the 3rd party send me over the call to this endpoint, they are getting the error message:
SOAP 1.1 fault: SOAP-ENV:Client [no subcode]
"No operation available for request {urn:dipatchClient}DispOutputRequest, please check the WSDL for the service."
Detail: [no detail]

I am creating a server endpoint (not a client).. Does anyone have any suggestions as to what is going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, MrMann. Can you clarify your question? WSDLs are used to create clients, but you say you're trying to create a server. Is this WSDL how the 3rd party wants to get data FROM YOU, or meant for you to consume FROM THEM?

Comment: Thanks Mike and @Keith-C. We build and distribute a client, which pulls messages out of our self hosted application and pushes them to an endpoint (to save the customer initiating the pull themselves). Now to format that message, we provide a WSDL for the customer to consume, and accept the incoming message and in this case, that is an app in Salesforce. So I've passed the WSDL to our parter who build this said app and they are receiving the error above. I've signed up as a developer and hit the same issue.

Comment: Ah, so you're trying to expose a web service. Can you share a sample of your code?

Comment: Using "Generate from WSDL" creates an Apex class that you can invoke to call out to the service described by the WSDL. So your Apex code is the client of the service defined by the WSDL and the WSDL includes the URL to call. In response to a button click or some other event, your Apex code invokes the service. There is no tooling in Salesforce to automatically create a server that conforms to some arbitrary WSDL. Salesforce offers a number of Web Service APIs. You need to give the Salesforce WSDL to the person creating the client and get them to adapt their code to your (Salesforce's) WSDL.

Comment: Converted my answer from earlier to the above comment now it is clearer what is being asked.